# using keycloak in with legacy system for provide OAuth2

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

we have legacy Backend which stored users with their password . we need create oAuth2 provider for our bussiness . there is recommendation to use Keycloak for this purpose . but

- can i import my users with hashed password to Keycloak ?
- is it good to use this service ?
- can you provide advice and recommendation ?